# how to get rid of the "unknown" section in the perf

Tags: c, linux, perf

what I did is:

```
1. sudo rm -rf /root/.debug/
2. compile program with -g -O2 -fno-omit-frame-pointer
3. run the program and get the pid
4. sudo perf record -F 2000 -a -s -g -p $pid sleep 15
5. sudo perf report
```

then I get a tiny part of "unknown", like

```
-    2.50%     0.00%  postgres  [unknown]            [k] 0000000000000000                                                                                                                                  
   - 0                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        1.12% _int_malloc                                                                                                                                                                                  ▒
        0.79% _IO_vsnprintf
```

looks this is due to libc 'malloc' call.  then I write a program on the **same machine** to test it.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    while(1) {
        printf("perf record -g -p %d -- sleep 5; perf report\n", getpid());
        sleep(1);
        void *p = malloc(10);
        memset(p, 0, 10);
        free(p);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

then I did the same thing as above,  there is no "unknown" section.

how to explain/fix this?

Comment: Unrelated, but you normally don't need root to profile your own processes.  Set `perf_event_paranoid` to allow something reasonable instead of using sudo all the time.  [Run perf without root-rights](//superuser.com/q/980632).  Except you're doing system-wide profiling for some reason, with `-a`.  Are you sure you want that instead of just profiling the process you're interested in?

Comment: Thanks @PeterCordes.  1.  do you mean my test is not running with `-a` option caused the difference?   I add the "-a" option and run it as root, It still has no "unknown" section in perf report.   2. about the sudo part,  my env allows me to use `sudo` or switch to root.  Thanks for the `perf_event_paranoid`,  I can try it later.  but will it make difference on the symbol "unknown" issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `[unknown]` block in the `perf report` output refers to the name of the dynamic shared object (**DSO**). `perf report` could not resolve the **DSO** path and hence it prints `[unknown]`. Per the latest kernel source code tree (which is 5.3.9 at the time of writing), you can see this [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.3.9/source/tools/perf/util/map.c#L410).

It is important to know that the determination of the DSO symbols happen with the help of the sampled event address. The function [thread__resolve](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.3.9/source/tools/perf/builtin-script.c#L1149) is responsible for doing exactly that. In older kernels, the `thread__resolve` method had another name - `perf_event__preprocess_sample_addr`.

Given the snapshot of your output, it looks like the address of the event that was sampled during `perf record`, is 0. This means that the address could not be resolved at all. It is an address in the kernel space (looking at the symbol `[k] 0000000000000000`) and `perf` in your case, could not resolve it.

The comments highlight setting `perf_event_paranoid` to a suitable value so that you can probe both kernel and user-space events successfully. Setting `perf_event_paranoid` to a value that allows you to correctly probe events in the kernel space should "be a step" towards correctly resolving the address.